# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a slow computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, intel-atom

I'm looking at installing Ubuntu on two computers that both have Intel Atom processors and only 1-2GB RAM. My experience is that Windows 7 is horribly bloated for these machines, and even Ubuntu 13.04 feels to heavy for good performance. (Perhaps Unity has a part in that?)

**Would it be better to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS rather than the newest version?**

My underlying idea is that older versions have less features and were built for the computers of their age. For these two machines, the actual OS doesn't matter at all because they will be used 97% for browsing Internet (Google, webmail, etc.).

(Yes, I realize that 10.04 is no longer supported on the desktop, but I don't think it's going to matter in this case.)

Comment: I used to run 7 on similar systems, they ran ok. I wonder in this case if the hexxeh chromium distro might be a suitable choice. I really do think a modern, supported OS is a better idea - maybe debian, or lubuntu? Considering lxde runs on raspberry pis, it should run on your atom boxen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should use a supported or a LTS version (12.04 LTS), due to security and other issues (outdated browser for example).

If you need more performance, use another window manager/desktop enviroment (eg. xfce or install xubuntu).

Comment: Security is a valid point! So now, I need to figure out what the most lightweight 12.04 desktop is. Maybe I ought to head over to AskUbuntu for that :)

Comment: If you have time to test, i suggest starting with Xubuntu - has all the features most users need, while still beingh lightweight enough for older computers. There are even more lightweight window managers, but are harder to use, and less user-friendly (fluxbox, twm,...)

Comment: Usability is important - this is for my family, not for myself.

Comment: There are a gazillions "lightweight" distros you can choose from. You find them described in www.distrowatch.com (which has a convenient search page to locate distros according to general criteria), or even wikipedia. Take a look at Puppy...